# How can I toggle image source only during input focus?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

**Summary:** I've created a search bar with three inputs: name, date of birth, and social security number. The functionality is all there, but I am attempting to elevate the design and am running into an issue on input focus.

[image: Search Bar example]

When the user selects the inputs, there are focus effects in my CSS. **What I am trying to do is toggle the images on input focus.** Currently they are written like this:

```
<div class="adv-searchbar__wrapper__search-box">
     <span class="column-1"><img src="/img/person-name.png" class="input-ico"/><input type="text" class="input" id="adv-input-1" placeholder="John Adam Smith"></span>
     <span class="column-2"><input type="date" class="input" id="adv-input-2" placeholder="MM / DD / YY"></span>
     <span class="column-3"><img src="/img/person-ssn.png" class="input-ico"/><input type="text" class="input" id="adv-input-3" placeholder="### - ## - ####"></span>
     <button type="submit" class="advSearchBtn"><img src="/img/search_white.png"/></button>
</div>
```

The user can either click the button to execute the next function, or use the Enter key.

**Effort:** I've tried using if-else statements in jQuery when the user Clicks an input. The issue with that that I've found is that I am not sure how to 'measure' when the user leaves the input. So while the image will change correctly, it will not change back once the user moves on.

```
$('.input').click(function() {
 let currIco = $(this)[0].previousSibling.src.slice(0, -4);
 if ($(this).is(':focus')) {
   console.log('input is focused');
     currIco = currIco + '__focus.png';
     $(this)[0].previousSibling.src = currIco;
 } else {
   console.log('input is blurred');
 }
});
```

I've found several tutorials for changing images on click or on hover, but I haven't been able to implement those solutions to my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say in a comment that the only reason you didn't use CSS is because the images are not in the input.

As CSS is still an option for you and it is *much easier* to achieve in CSS (plus you haven't got a JS answer yet), take a look at the solution below.

FYI CSS-only is also a more *efficient* option - the more client-side processing you add, the slower the page load and the worse for SEO and user experience.

```css
.column-1 input, .column-3 input {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top left;
  padding-left: 40px;
}
.column-1 input {
  background-image: url(https://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-30-30-1.jpg);
}
.column-1 input:focus {
  background-image: url(https://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-30-30-2.jpg);
}
.column-3 input {
  background-image: url(https://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-30-30-3.jpg);
}
.column-3 input:focus {
  background-image: url(https://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-30-30-4.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div class="adv-searchbar__wrapper__search-box">
  <span class="column-1">
         <input type="text" class="input" id="adv-input-1" placeholder="John Adam Smith">
     </span>
  <span class="column-2"><input type="date" class="input" id="adv-input-2" placeholder="MM / DD / YY"></span>
  <span class="column-3"><input type="text" class="input" id="adv-input-3" placeholder="### - ## - ####"></span>
  <button type="submit" class="advSearchBtn"><img src="/img/search_white.png"/></button>
</div>
```

Obviously I haven't applied your styling to the inputs because you hadn't included it, but you can apply that the same way excluding the image.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an other way, using focus on parent element.

```css
span:focus-within .input-ico-focus { 
  display: inline-block;
}
span:focus-within .input-ico { 
  display: none 
}
span .input-ico-focus { 
  display: none 
}
span .input-ico { 
  display: inline-block; 
}
.input-ico, .input-ico-focus {
  width: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div>
     <span class="column-1">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pd8J3.png" class="input-ico">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdkNO.png" class="input-ico-focus">
      <input type="text" class="input" id="adv-input-1" placeholder="John Adam Smith">
     </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could, alternatively to the existing answer (provided by FluffyKitten), create a `<label>` element and place it after the `<input>`.

I too, don't recommend using `JavaScript` over `CSS` if you are indeed able to get it done in `CSS`.

> In this case, you can separate the icon (and therefore the styling) from the rest of the input field if you so desire.

```css
.adv-searchbar__wrapper__search-box span {
  position: relative;
}

.input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 2px 2px 2px 20px;
  max-height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
}

.input~.icon {
  position: absolute;
  left: 2px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/16?text=icon');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.input:focus~.icon {
  filter: blur(1px);
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/16/FF9900');
}
```

```html
<div class="adv-searchbar__wrapper__search-box">
  <span class="column-1">
    <input type="text" class="input" id="adv-input-1" placeholder="John Adam Smith">
    <label class="icon" for="adv-input-1"></label>
  </span>
  <span class="column-2">
    <input type="date" class="input" id="adv-input-2" placeholder="MM / DD / YY">
  </span>
  <span class="column-3">
    <input type="text" class="input" id="adv-input-3" placeholder="### - ## - ####">
    <label class="icon" for="adv-input-3"></label>
  </span>
  <button type="submit" class="advSearchBtn">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/16?text=&nbsp;"/>
  </button>
</div>
```